# Roblox - Scripts not firing

Tags: lua, roblox

I'm making an inventory system, and I have been trying to make it so I can move items between the hotbar and backpack. The scripts work perfectly fine at first, but then when I do one of the actions the other one doesn't work. I am posting the entire script if you need it but the problems are at the bottom 2 for loops.

```
game.StarterGui:SetCoreGuiEnabled(Enum. CoreGuiType. Backpack, false)

local replicatedStorage = game.ReplicatedStorage
local userInputService
local toolFolder = replicatedStorage.ToolFolder
local images = replicatedStorage.Images
local uis = game:GetService("UserInputService")
local player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
local playergui = player.PlayerGui

local inventory = playergui:WaitForChild("Inventory")
local hotbar = inventory.Hotbar
local inventoryFrame = inventory.Inventory
local itemFrame = inventoryFrame.ScrollingFrame

local hotbarTable = {}
local inventoryTable = {}
local insertedItems = {}
local keyConversions = {
    [Enum.KeyCode.One] = 1,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Two] = 2,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Three] = 3,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Four] = 4,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Five] = 5,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Six] = 6,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Seven] = 7,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Eight] = 8,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Nine] = 9,
    [Enum.KeyCode.Zero] = 10,
}

local function pickSlot()
    for i, v in pairs(hotbarTable) do
        if v.Item == "None" then
            return i
        end
    end
end

local function addItem(item)
    local slot = pickSlot()
    if slot ~= nil then
        hotbarTable[slot].Item = item
        hotbarTable[slot].Count = 1
        hotbarTable[slot].Image = images[item].Texture
        table.insert(insertedItems, item)
    elseif slot == nil then
        inventoryTable[item] = {
            Count = 1;
            Image = images[item].Texture
        }
    end
end


local function fillInventoryTables()
    for i = 1, 10 do
        hotbarTable[i] = {
            Item = "None";
            Count = 0;
            Image = "None"
        }
    end
    for i, v in pairs(toolFolder:GetChildren()) do
        if #insertedItems > 0 then
            if table.find(insertedItems, v.Name) then
                for x, c in pairs(hotbarTable) do
                    if c.Item == v.Name then
                        c.Count += 1
                    end
                end
            else
                addItem(v.Name)
            end
        else
            addItem(v.Name)
        end
    end
end

local function display()
    for i, v in pairs(hotbarTable) do
        hotbar[i].Image = v.Image
        hotbar[i].Counter.Text = v.Count
    end 
    for i, v in pairs(inventoryTable) do
        local clone = inventoryFrame.ScrollingFrame.Sample:Clone()
        clone.Visible = true
        clone.Name = tostring(i)
        clone.Parent = inventoryFrame.ScrollingFrame
        clone.Image = v.Image
        clone.Counter.Text = v.Count
    end
end

local function Equip(key)
    local tool = hotbarTable[key].Item
    if player.Character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Tool") then
        if player.Character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Tool").Name == tool then
            player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid"):UnequipTools()
            player.Backpack[tool]:Destroy()
        elseif player.Character:FindFirstChildOfClass("Tool").Name ~= tool then
            player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid"):UnequipTools()
            player.Backpack:GetChildren()[1]:Destroy()
            toolFolder[tool]:Clone().Parent = player.Backpack
            player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid"):EquipTool(player.Backpack:GetChildren()[1])
        end
    elseif not player.Character:FindFirstChild(tool) then
        toolFolder[tool]:Clone().Parent = player.Backpack
        player.Character:FindFirstChild("Humanoid"):EquipTool(player.Backpack:GetChildren()[1])
    end
end

local function removeInventoryFrames()
    for i, v in pairs(inventoryFrame.ScrollingFrame:GetChildren()) do
        if v.ClassName == "ImageButton" and v.Name ~= "Sample" then
            v:Destroy()
        end
    end
end

fillInventoryTables()
hotbarTable[1].Item = "None"
hotbarTable[1].Count = 0
hotbarTable[1].Image = "None"
display()

uis.InputBegan:Connect(function(key)
    if key.UserInputType == Enum.UserInputType.Keyboard then
        Equip(keyConversions[key.KeyCode])
    end
end)

-- Moving items from backpack to hotbar
for i, v in ipairs(inventoryFrame.ScrollingFrame:GetChildren()) do
    if v.ClassName == "ImageButton" then
        v.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
            print(1)
            for x, c in pairs(hotbarTable) do
                if c.Item == "None" then
                    c.Item = v
                    c.Count = v.Counter.Text
                    c.Image = v.Image
                    inventoryTable[v.Name] = nil
                    removeInventoryFrames()
                    display()
                end
            end
        end)
    end
end 

-- Moving items from hotbar to backpack
for i, v in ipairs(hotbar:GetChildren()) do
    if v.ClassName == "ImageButton" then
        v.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
            inventoryTable[v.Name] = {
                Count = hotbarTable[tonumber(v.Name)].Count;
                Image = hotbarTable[tonumber(v.Name)].Image
            }
            hotbarTable[tonumber(v.Name)].Item = "None"
            hotbarTable[tonumber(v.Name)].Count = 0
            hotbarTable[tonumber(v.Name)].Image = "None"
            print(v.Name)
            removeInventoryFrames()
            display()
        end)
    end
    print(hotbarTable)
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the following function the previous buttons get destroyed so there is no mousebutton1click function after calling display(). Just add back the mousebutton1click function when rebuilding the hotbar buttons. I hope this makes sense to you.

```lua
removeInventoryFrames()
```